# Visual Studio 2017 Install Stuck at Microsoft.VisualStudio.AspNet45.Feature

Tags: visual-studio

When installing Visual Studio 2017 Professional 15.9.0 the installation hangs at 97% while installing Microsoft.VisualStudio.AspNet45.Feature.

I'm posting this only because it seems to be a problem that is almost two years and is still an issue.

There are several posts like this one:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/24739/installation-stuck-at-applying-microsoftvisualstud.html#reply-form

Most indicate the issue has been fixed in later versions, but that doesn't seem to be the case.  I let the process run over night and it never went anywhere.

Answer (score 8):

**If you encounter the issue of your Visual Studio installer becoming stuck while installing ASP.Net45.Feature, you need to do the following:**

1. [Alt + Ctrl + Del] to open Task Manager.
2. Locate a process named "Dism Image Servicing Utility".
3. View the "**Dism Image Servicing Utility**" Properties -> Details tab.
4. Confirm that the ***Original Filename is* "DISM.EXE"** in the Details tab.
5. Close Properties and **End Task.** (Note: If you have two of these processes in the Task Manager, just kill the bottom-most one. You can leave the second one running since for some Microsoft reason, **killing just one does the trick**).
6. Enjoy the completion of your Visual Studio installation. Once the process is killed, the install continues immediately.

Comment: this problem still happened with the 2022 enterprise installer. killing that one process still fixed it for me. thanks

Comment: Tbh, I find that hysterical but for all of the wrong reasons. See you here in 2045! :)

Answer (score 4):

There was a process name DISM.exe in task manager. I killed it and it work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i found that a "Service Host: Local System" process was taking up 20% cpu and 20% disk.  Nested in that was Windows Update, and Update Orchestrator Service....

[image]

I killed both of those and the installation completed.

Upon rebooting, my machine sat for almost an hour on the "Getting Windows Ready (please do not turn off your computer)" update screen, but it did eventually finish.